# When doing a Subversion commit "--This line, and those below, will be ignored--"

Tags: svn, commit

this is my first question on stackoverflow so please excuse if I do not submit properly.

I am attempting to commit 'folder2/folder3/file' via terminal (Mac OS X). Everything is fine up until the svn ci portion where I get the following.

```
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

A    Folder1/folder2
A    Folder1/folder2/folder3
AM   Folder1/folder2/folder3/file

-uu-:---F1  svn-commit.4.tmp   All L1     (Fundamental)--------------------------------------------
Loading vc…done
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like to me you are in the commit message edit phase - that line and the line below are for your information, it is telling you what is being changed, etc.  If you add a message above that line and save - it should commit the file.

If you are doing this command line, you can bypass this by adding the commit message to the command:
`svn ci -m "COMMIT MESSAGE"`

Comment: what if I'm getting this when I try to create a branch?